# Is it possible to program a hall-effect sensor with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, programming, hall-effect

On pg. 18 Figure 5 of [this data sheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/SIP-Package-Zero-To-Thousand-Amp-Sensor-ICs/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A1360-1-2-Datasheet.ashx) you will see a pulse train that allows for programming the sensitivity of the A1362 Hall-Effect sensor.  So far I have tried to manually apply required voltage pulses (high,mid,low) as defined in the data sheet with no success.

Will I have better luck using an Arduino?  I though this link was interesting, but I'm not sure if it is what I need:

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Could someone point me to either a microcontroller that can program a hall-effect sensor or
sample microcontroller code that programs any sensor using PWM?

Comment: I provided an answer but when I looked at the voltages, you have to use up to 27V, which is very high, so you'd need circuitry to generate 27V from 5V using a DC/DC boost and then use some sort of switch to create the pulse train.

Comment: If you're comfortable with doing it manually (its a one time thing, it seems, but its a lot of pulses to count and keep track of), it looks like it should work. A PWM will not help you. An arduino or any microcontroller can, although the voltage levels involved will need some extra circuitry to build.

Comment: And if you try to do this manually (using switches and a 27V power supply) pay attentions to the bouncing of your switches. You may thing that you are sending only one "1" bit when was is actually on the cable is 10's of "1 0 1 0 1 0" due to the bounces of your switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Allegro datasheet suggests programming using either their sensor evaluation kit ($500), or using a programmable power supply. You can find a suitable usb programmable psu on ebay ($150 or so). Check that software is available to create a pulse train (really a step train).